# linux cannot ping google.com

Tags: linux, dns, ping

I can connect to my wifi (another laptop is fine on this network), however the browser will not load web pages, and I cannot ping google.com

One strange thing I have noticed is that if I look in /etc/resolv.conf the following lines are present:

```
#Generated by Network Manager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

Where I am sure the second line should be 8.8.4.4. So I change the second line to this and check again that the change has been implemented.........which it has.

However, I then reconnected to the wifi and my changes had been wiped and had changed back to:

```
#Generated by Network Manager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

Is this behavior normal?

This problem is also intermittent. Sometimes my browser works fine and I can ping google.com, others times I get this problem.

What seems to be the issue?

## update:

I can successfully ping google by IP (216.239.39.99)

browser still not able to load websites however.

Answer (score 0):

Wether this is conincidence or not, in my chrome browser I went into advanced settings and turned off the "allow google to predict urls" option and voila I know have internet.